# Image Files Uploaded via REST got Temporary status - Cannot be refereced by Media Image

Tags: media, files, 8

Drupal 8.9.11

Image File Uploaded via REST gets "status - Temporary" while setting explicitly "status" case to True server error 403 (code in python)

```
   "status": [
      {
        "value": True
      }
   ],
```

The sever returns code 403, an exception:

```
Status: 403, Message: {"message":"Access denied on creating field \u0027status\u0027."}
```

The error on the server:
$ vendor/bin/drush watchdog-show

```
access denied Warning Path: /themag_dp8/entity/file?_format=hal_json.
   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: Access denied on creating
   field 'status'. in Drupal\rest\Plugin\rest\resou
```

If I'll not specify "status = true" The next REST call to Create Media fails to reference it due to its temporary status.

```
   payload = {
        "name": {
            "value": name
        },
        "field_image": [
            {
                "target_id": file_id
            }
        ],
        "field_description": [
            {
                "value": description
            },
        ],
        "bundle": [
            {
                "target_id": "image"
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": oauth.base_url + REST_TYPE_MEDIA_IMAGE
            },
            oauth.base_url + "/rest/relation/media/image/thumbnail": [
                {
                    "href": oauth.base_url + "/file/%d" % file_id + FORMAT_HAL_JSON
                }
            ],
            oauth.base_url + "/rest/relation/media/image/field_image": [
                {
                    "href": oauth.base_url + "/file/%d" % file_id + FORMAT_HAL_JSON
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

```
Status: 422, Message: {"message":"Unprocessable Entity: validation failed.\nfield_image.0.target_id:
This entity (file: 119) cannot be referenced.\n"}
```

Server error:
$ vendor/bin/drush watchdog-show

```
access denied Warning 
    Path: /themag_dp8/entity/paragraph?_format=hal_json.
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException:  in
    Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 120 of
php           Error   
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnprocessableEntityHttpException: Unprocessable Entity:
    validation failed.
    field_image.0.target_id: This entity (file: 119) cannot be referenced.
    in
```

When I manually, via web site admin (https://drupal8.site/admin/content/files), change the file status to "Permanent", this Create Media REST call succeeds to create a new media/image entity.

Seems the Rest user missing some security allowances, but which one?
Did anybody succeed to create a node consisting of the teaser image, paragraph video and so?

Sure I'm not the first who attack this issue, where the relevant documentation, working code examples?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found so far is to fix a Drupal module code:

modules\contrib\file_entity\src\Normalizer\FileEntityNormalizer.php
on line 48 add:

```php
$entity->setPermanent();
```

*See:*

- [Which Drupal 8.1.x Rest API property in the JSON request controls
  Drupal's File status (Temporary and Permanent) logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849454/which-drupal-8-1-x-rest-api-property-in-the-json-request-controls-drupals-file)
- [Files created with REST API are only temporary](https://www.drupal.org/node/2756127)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload images and create media without the File Entity module and any module fixes.

*Try this:*

[New "file_upload" REST resource plugin: allows file uploads of any size, creates File entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/2941420)

In your case, the request would be like this:

```
POST /file/upload/media/image/field_media_image?_format=hal_json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: file; filename="filename.jpg"

[… binary file data …]
```

And request to create media /entity/media?_format=hal_json:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "type": {
            "href": "YOUR_SITE/rest/type/media/image"
        }
    },
    "name": [
        {
            "value": "Image.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "field_media_image": [
        {
            "target_id": YOUR_ID
        }
    ]
}
```

It's works fine.